# Integral does not make sense?!

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a (seemingly) silly question. I wish to calculate the integral:
$$
\int x^{d}dx
$$
 and 
$$
\int x^{(1-d)}dx.
$$
Integrating the first integral, I obtain:
$$
\int x^{d}dx=\frac{1}{d+1}x^{d+1}+C
$$
 Integrating the second integral, I obtain:
$$
\int x^{(1-d)}dx.=-\frac{1}{d}x^{-d}+C
$$
Both of these integrals should be exactly the same when $d=\frac{1}{2}$.
But this does not seem to be the case! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the derivative of $x^{-d}$?

Comment: $(1-d)+1=2-d$, not $-d$.

Comment: hence justifying the "silly" in my question

Comment: Note that your first equation doesn’t hold for $d=-1$, nor does the second for $d=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself.

$\int x^{(1-d)}dx.=\frac{1}{2-d}x^{2-d}+C$